# Why would EmberJS not render in my HTML / Handlebars on webkit browsers

Tags: cordova, webkit, ember.js

I have a really basic EmberJS application started that I want to use within a phonegap application. The following code works great in FF 4 but in Chrome and Safari the view is not updated in the handlebars section.

The Main JS file has the following code.

```js
(function(window) {
  function Main() {
    MainApp = Ember.Application.create({
      appname: "My App",
      ready: function() {
        console.log("hello from ember");
        app.initialize();
        app.deviceready();
      }
    });
  }
  window.Main = Main;
}(window))
```

**I found that if I removed the self executing function it will render just fine in webkit**

```js
MainApp = Ember.Application.create({
  appname: "My App",
  ready: function() {
    console.log("hello from ember");
    app.initialize();
    app.deviceready();
  }
});
```

So I guess the real question is why does wrapping Ember.Application.create() into a Main() function cause this issue in webkit ?

In my index.html file I have the following script block to execute main.js

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function init() {
    var mainApp = new Main();
  }
</script>
```

Then my handlebars code looks like so.

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h1>hello from {{MainApp.appname}}</h1>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be to take

```
(function(window) {
  function Main() {
    MainApp = Ember.Application.create({
      appname: "My App",
      ready: function() {
        console.log("hello from ember");
        app.initialize();
        app.deviceready();
      }
    });
  }
  window.Main = Main;
}(window))
```

and make it

```
(function(window) {
  MainApp = Ember.Application.create({
    appname: "My App",
    ready: function() {
      console.log("hello from ember");
      app.initialize();
      app.deviceready();
    }
  });
})(window)
```

This will still assign MainApp to window/global context as you wanted, but removes the dependency of the uninitialized function. I'm not sure how you were calling the `init()` function in your HTML, but it seems as though it was never actually initializing a `new Main()` object for you.